# Is there a topological space whose fundamental group is the real numbers?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Most of the examples of fundamental groups have been "discrete" in nature. I'm wondering if there is an example which is not like that. A possible preliminary question could be if there is a space whose fundamental group is the rationals.

Edit: This has been marked as a duplicate; it is with respect to my subquestion about rationals however the linked answer does not say anything about topological spaces whose fundamental groups are the real numbers.

Comment: Every group is the fundamental group of some space.

Comment: The real or rational numbers just viewed as a group don't have any intrinsic continuous structure.

Comment: Your edit is not quite correct: read the accepted answer there.

Comment: right, it says that for every group G there is a space whose fundamental group is G. However I was hoping to get an example in the case of $\mathbb{R}$. I suppose you could use the presentation space in one of the answers but I don't see exactly how that would work.

Comment: Every group $G$ has a canonical presentation whose generators consist of every element $g \in G$ and whose relations consist of the entire multiplication table $g \cdot h = gh$ of $G$. So you can always take the presentation complex associated to this presentation. (Carrying this idea further leads to a construction of what is called the classifying space $BG$ of $G$.)